# Trouble scraping Div class with same class Ids with Xpath

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

[image: I'm trying to scrape the Body style but having trouble pulling it]

https://www.maplesford.com/new-Warsaw-2022-Ford-Escape-SEL-1FMCU9H97NUB34573

```
body_style = response.xpath(".//div[@class='vdp-info-media vdp-body-style']/text()").get()
```

My issue is I can't seem to drop the levels down to pull the body style. stuck at /text() don't know how to pull the body style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
body_style = response.xpath("//li[@class='vdp-info media vdp-body-style']//h3/text()").get()
```

Check Scrapy docs [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/)